# Не работает OnDrag, но работает OnMouseDown

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DragAndDropGame : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler
{

    Camera MainCamera;

    void Awake()
    {
        MainCamera = Camera.allCameras[0];
        Debug.Log(MainCamera);
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnBeginDrag");
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector3 newPos = MainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(eventData.position);
        newPos.z = 0;
        transform.position = newPos;
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnMouseDown");
    }
}
```

`OnMouseDown` отрабатывает, а реализации `IBeginDragHandler`, `IDragHandler` - нет. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0):

`IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler` находятся в пространстве имён `UnityEngine.EventSystems` и используют для работы `EventSystem`. Если точнее, то эта система кидает рейкасты, собирает с точек попадания свои интерфейсы и производит вызов.

Метод же `OnMouseDown` принадлежит `MonoBehaviour` и реализуется просто через прокидывание рейкаста из всех камер.

Можете посмотреть, в `UnityEngine.EventSystems` так же присутствуют интерфейс `IPointerDownHandler`, который является аналогом `OnMouseDown`.

В вашем случае, если `OnMouseDown` работает, а интерфейсы нет, то на сцене отсутствует объект класс `EventSystem`. Нажмите ПКМ в иерархии и создайте его из меню UI->EventSystem